# Search two columns in Microsoft excel 2013 and set the value of a third column with a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I want to search a specific text which is the `firstname_lastname` e.g `John_Smith` in `worksheetA`. `WorksheetA` has a column `firstname` and another column `lastname`. So after knowing which row has the firstname and lastname I searched for, I want to set the value of cell in the same row with a specific value.

For example if this is my worksheet:

```
Firstname     Lastname     Found
Matt          Damon        No
Smith         Andrew       No
John          Smith        No
Tom           Mark         No
```

and my search word is `John_Smith` the result will be

```
Firstname     Lastname     Found
Matt          Damon        No
Smith         Andrew       No
John          Smith        Yes
Tom           Mark         No
```

Any advice please how this can be done in VBA excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example, split the string into two separate strings. Then loop through the range.

The set up
[image]

The Code

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim e As String, a As String, b As String
    Dim Rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))

    e = Range("E1")
    a = Left(e, InStr(e, "_") - 1)
    b = Right(e, InStr(e, "_"))

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = a And c.Offset(0, 1) = b Then c.Offset(0, 2) = "Yes"
    Next c

End Sub
```

The Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Because you seem to actually want a third column which actually says "yes" / "no", this is fairly straightforward. Assuming your search term is in E2 [in the form of FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME], simply put this in cell C2 and drag down:

```
=IF(A2&"_"&B2=$E$2,"Yes","No")
```

Then you can either add a new column that checks if that row in column C = "Yes", and if it does, add the value there. Or, replace "Yes" with your special value already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there anyway to do so without dragging down? As I want it in a kind of search then insert.

Comment: @Tak There is a way to do so without dragging down, but then you won't have a column which says "Yes" / "No" on every row, which was what your question requested. What is it that you actually want?

Comment: I don't want it to say "Yes" or "No" on every row, it will just place "yes" in a specific column of this row which matches the query.

Comment: @Tak Then you have 2 options: Use my formula above, but replace "No" with "". Or, use a VBA solution, such as the other answer proposed for this question. Without VBA, you can't make Excel go to a specific cell and change the value there [without invisibly affecting all cells in that column, or something like that].